# Download file from URL throws status code 406

Tags: vba, excel, winhttprequest

Hi guys I have this sub I want to download a file from URL but everytime when I run it `WinHttpReq.Status` contains `406`.

```
Sub DownloadFile()
    Dim myURL As String
    myURL = "https://YourWebSite.com/?your_query_parameters"

    Dim WinHttpReq As Object
    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "username", "password"
    WinHttpReq.send

    myURL = WinHttpReq.responseBody
    If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        oStream.Type = 1
        oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
        oStream.SaveToFile "C:\file.csv", 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
        oStream.Close
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> The 406 status code means that, although the server understood and processed the request, the response is of a form the client cannot understand. A client sends, as part of a request, headers indicating what types of data it can use, and a 406 error is returned when the response is of a type not in that list.

Eg. If you ask the server to send a *GIF picture*, but it can only send *plain text* and *PNG pictures* you will receive a 406 status code meaning your server understood your question but cannot fulfill it.

So you should include an `Accept` header specifying which type of media you want your server to send to your client (your VBA), and that type should be a type that your server can actually deliver.

Example how to send headers:

```
WinHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8"
WinHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "text/xml"
```

Of course nobody can tell you which media type is the correct because we don't know your server and which type of media it can provide.

Comment: Thank you so much the link will download a CSV file

Comment: You need to figure out which media types your server can send. A csv file can be sent in different media types